# Контроль приложений Windows (аудит)

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript

Появилась задача контроля программного обеспечения на АРМ-е пользователя. ОС - Windows 7/10.

**Цель - контроль целостности рабочего места**.

**Задача - проверка на целостность исполнимых модулей и наличие новых программных модулей**.

Т.е. существует угроза того, что пользователь несанкционировано расширит свои права и установит нежелательное ПО (игры, мультимедия, иное ПО в формате portable и т.д.).
Вариант ограничить права на АРМ-е (политикой белых/черных списков, ограничения доступа к файлам и реестру) не подходит по многим причинам.

Отсюда возникает главный вопрос, **как реализовать встроенными средствами операционной системы контроль/учет файловой системы**?

Предполагается, что считывание контрольного файла с описанием стандартной конфигурации АРМ-а будет происходить по сети, либо с внешнего накопителя.
Из вышеуказанного вопроса возникают следующие:

**Какой инструмент** лучше подходит по параметру производительности: VBscript, Powershell, CMD, какая-нибудь внешняя CRC-утилита  (Freeware)?

Исходя из требований к производительности, **какие алгоритмы** контроля использовать: расчет CRC32, md5 и т.д.?

Возможно существует **иная модель контроля**: анализ аудита событий, запуска исполнимых модулей и т.д., которая по итогу проверки выявит появление новых файлов в форме списка?

P.S. Речь идет об использовании встроенного ПО или небольших сторонних бесплатных утилит (запускаемых с внешнего ресурса: сеть, накопитель), поскольку установить дополнительное ПО проблематично - политика ИБ: в частности, лицензионные ограничения.

Answer (score 1):

**Непосредственно ответ**

Подход нужен комплексный - в первую очередь, пообрезать политиками запуск программ откуда не надо - флешки, сетевые шары, папки вне program files и windows - это уже серьезно затруднит внедрение левого софта.

Можно повключать всевозможный аудит, но кто потом будет эти километры логов изучать?
Учтите, что когда на компьютере стоят всевозможные средства обеспечения безопасности, а еще хуже зоопарк из ник (типа кашпировского, который сам не прочь что-то стырить + сикрет нета), машина из i5 плавно превращается в Celeron 566 мегагерц, а пользователи начинают плеваться.

**Критика вашего подхода**

Вам не хватает двух шагов, которые нужно сделать до того, начинать *держать и не пущать*.

1. Построить адекватную модель работы пользователя. Если это офисный кнопкотых, меры будут одни, если это разработка ПО - другие, если разработка железа - третьи.
2. Построить адекватную модель угроз, с опорой на знания пользователя. Нет смысла защищаться от секретарши - у нее квалификации не хватит на то, чтобы что-то там сломать, да и мотивации такой нет. Другое дело, что у секретарши может быть сынишка-кулхацкер, но это уже решается физическим контролем доступа.

Comment: Я не просто так сказал, что есть ограничения по изменению состава АРМа. Это АРМ АСУ ТП, соответственно, легальное обновление состава ПО его произойдет только при модернизации всей АСУ ТП. А это явление наступает, как следует из практики, не скоро - хорош если через 10 лет. Проблема в том, что на момент создания АСУшки в ТЗ **не были** прописаны требования по безопасности. Отсюда техническое решение контроля: **КОСТЫЛИ** в виде скриптов и пр.Организационные меры - это само собой.Отсюда и задача - определить факт изменений. Анализ изменений это уже организационно-техническая задача реагирования.

Comment: Стоп, у вас что, АСУТП воткнута в Интернет? Или порты USB не опломбированы?

Comment: Нет, не  в Интернет. Часть АРМов в технолгической сети, где можно разместить внешние вспомогательные ресурсы (конфиги, скрипты и прочее). Есть изолированные АРМы - отсюда есть желание хранить контрольные суммы и запускать средства проверкки (скрипты/утилиты) с внешних носителей (USB-флешки, SD-карты и т.д.). USB-порты опять же не можем прикрыть - периферия (мышь/клава). Да да, можно отключить драйвер внешних накопителей, но  есть мероприятия по ручной выгрузке сформированных отчетов.

Comment: А на дисках АРМ вообще что-то должно изменяться? Может, имеет смысл при загрузке раскатывать все из образа?

Comment: Тут важно обнаружение факта изменения АРМа, нежели процедура его восстановления (которая уже имеется, в том числе и из образов). Ну не предоставил производитель средства по накладыванию внешних средств защиты. Загрузки по сети, с эталонным образом и прочее :-(

Comment: Самый примитивный вариант - грузиться со флешки, на которой есть эталонный дамп, после чего запускать rsync между АРМ и эталоном - если rsync нашел, что синхронизировать - значит, были изменения

Comment: Остановка АРМа - очень нежелательна. А мероприятия контроля планируем производить в период минимальной нагрузки, отсюда требования к производительности.

Comment: Используя ОС от АРМа для контроля целостности АРМа вы не имеете никаких гарантий, что контроль валиден. Вирус может легко подсунуть контролирующей программе липу.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100737/discussion-between-gbg-and-daemon-5).